# usermod command not working on solaris

Tags: solaris, usermod

I am trying to add one more group in already added supplementary groups for a user.
`rcc` is the name of the supplementary group I need to add
`sm254040` is the user id.

when I run the command

```
usermod -a -G rcc sm254040
```

I am getting the below error:

```
UX: usermod: ERROR: Invalid syntax
```

What should I use to append a supplementary group in already added supplementary groups?

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris 11, you use `-G +groupname` to add a supplementary group to a user with `usermod`. This is described in [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/usermod-1m.html).

```
usermod -G +rcc sm254040
```

With Solaris 10, you would have to specify all supplementary groups, including the new group, as a comma-delimited list to the `-G` option, as the `usermod` utility does not understand the `+` prefix syntax available in later Solaris releases, possibly through using something like:

```
usermod -G "$( id -Gn sm254040 | tr ' ' ',' ),rcc" sm254040
```

This (which is untested) would use `id -Gn sm254040` to get the current groups of the user, and then `tr` to change the spaces into commas.  This list is then appended to with the new group name and the amended list is handed to `usermod -G`.

Comment: can you write the command please

Comment: I am getting below error:

UX: usermod: ERROR: group +rcc does not exist.  Choose another.
UX: usermod: +rcc name should be all lower case or numeric.

Comment: @tanijoshi See updated answer. Could you please confirm what release of Solaris you are currently running?

Comment: I am currently using solaris 10. thanks for the information.